# 15-second idle delay loading Windows native Python module

Tags: python, windows, cython

I'm developing a native Python module (DLL or PYD) on Windows using Cython. Every time I rebuild it, the first time it's loaded blocks for 15 seconds, during which time the CPU and disk are completely idle. Subsequent attempts run normally, until I rebuild the module again.

This happens with both the Cygwin and MSYS2 builds of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the Avira antivirus. Disabling its real-time protection fixed the problem. I eventually replaced it with Avast, which so far hasn't given me any trouble.